# Error consuming WCF Service in Android

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, wcf

I am trying to POST data to my database using WCF service but can't seem to figure what is wrong with my code, I have tried different solutions but all of it seems to fail. I am new to android development and do not know how to debug. Please help me...

**Here is my code:**

**WCF Service:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAllocationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "StrongestWifi",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void UpdateStrongestWifi(myWifiClass myWifiClass);

}

[DataContract]
public class myWifiClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Time")]
    public string Time
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "SignalStrength")]
    public string SignalStrength
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "SSID")]
    public string SSID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

**Android Code:**

```
public void onGetWebService(View v)
{
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/StrongestWifi");
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JSONStringer getWifiInfo;
    try {
        getWifiInfo = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
                .key("myWifiClass")
                    .object()
                        .key("Time").value("TIME")                                  
                        .key("SignalStrength").value("Strength")
                        .key("SSID").value("ID")
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getWifiInfo.toString());

    request.setEntity(entity);

    // Send request to WCF service
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Log Cat:**

> 06-01 15:46:06.229: W/System.err(27711): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   06-01 15:46:06.237: W/System.err(27711):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   06-01 15:46:06.237: W/System.err(27711):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>   06-01 15:46:06.237: W/System.err(27711):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>   06-01 15:46:06.237: W/System.err(27711):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>   06-01 15:46:06.245: W/System.err(27711):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>   06-01 15:46:06.245: W/System.err(27711):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>   06-01 15:46:06.245: W/System.err(27711):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
>   06-01 15:46:06.245: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   06-01 15:46:06.245: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at com.example.pcsprojectnetworkcodes.MainActivity.onGetWebService(MainActivity.java:191)
>   06-01 15:46:06.253: W/System.err(27711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   06-01 15:46:06.261: W/System.err(27711):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-01 15:46:06.269: W/System.err(27711):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-01 15:46:06.269: W/System.err(27711):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
>   06-01 15:46:06.276: W/System.err(27711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-01 15:46:06.276: W/System.err(27711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-01 15:46:06.276: W/System.err(27711):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
>   06-01 15:46:06.276: W/System.err(27711):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
>   06-01 15:46:06.284: W/System.err(27711):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dont make Network call on main thread as it may crash application**.try to call this httpClient.execute(request) in **asyntask** or using **runnable** thread.

Comment: i tried using asyntask but did not quite understand how and where to use it, could you give me a headstart? thanks!

Comment: just do onGetWebService() functionality using doInbackground() mtd of Asynctask.call asynctask.execute from oncreate mtd of activity.

Comment: The error disappears but I face yet another problem, thanks!!